# HELP Failed installation of ubuntu possibly deleted windows

Tags: boot, windows

I was trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my custom desktop.

During installation I chose to install Ubuntu along with Windows 10. The next option was to select drive and allocate drive space. I chose the C drive were Windows 10 was installed, and distributed the disk space equally for both windows and Ubuntu.

I pressed continue, and it started to process and it gave me a error message. I can't remember what the message said. It was late at night, so I decided to try installation next day.

Next day I booted my PC and Windows was gone from the boot manager. This seemed strange as I never got to commence Ubuntu installation. I assumed my boot manager was broken. I tried repair my PC option, and I tried command prompts that can fix the boot manager that I found searching online, nothing fixed it.

I took my PC to a repair shop and they told me my windows partition was deleted. This seemed so strange, how can I have deleted my Windows partition if I never fully installed Ubuntu in the first place? Did I actually deleted it and I have to reinstall it? What can I do? Please help

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to reinstall Windows and try again. 
If you have another Windows machine the easiest would be via [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). You'll need at least an 8GB USB drive for it to work.
If you only have a Linux machine available you can download an ISO disk image from the same link and use **UNetbootin** tool to make a bootable usb.

Answer (score -2):

Try running [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Chances are that it will be able to fix your problem. This program has never let me down for issues like these. If it doesn't fix it, you might just be out of luck and need to reinstall windows again or use a file recovery program.

Comment: Yes, you probably have to reinstall Windows if you want windows on the system. You can also proceed to install Ubuntu. If you have important files that you don't have backup of, you have a very good chance of recovering them, if you **don't** use the computer for anything else in the meantime.

Comment: I suggested boot -repair because I thought his windows bootloader was deleted, if that's the case boot-repair would be able to fix this. Ubuntu has the tendency to do that, but yeah if it was the  whole system was deleted, (entire C:\ drive) that's a different story.